# How can I authenticate when querying druid?

Tags: authentication, authorization, druid

I installed druid from [link attached here](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/index.html)  to install druid.

The following code has been added to the common.runtime.properties file .

```
# Basic Security

druid.auth.authenticatorChain=["MyBasicAuthenticator"]
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicAuthenticator.type=basic
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicAuthenticator.initialAdminPassword=password1
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicAuthenticator.initialInternalClientPassword=password2
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicAuthenticator.authorizerName=MyBasicAuthorizer

## Creating an Escalator
# Escalator
druid.escalator.type=basic
druid.escalator.internalClientUsername=druid_system
druid.escalator.internalClientPassword=password2
druid.escalator.authorizerName=MyBasicAuthorizer


druid.auth.authorizers=["MyBasicAuthorizer"]
druid.auth.authorizer.MyBasicAuthorizer.type=basic
```

Also, `"druid-basic-security"` is added to `druid.extensions.loadList`

```
druid.extensions.loadList=["druid-hdfs-storage", "druid-kafka-indexing-service", "druid-datasketches", "druid-basic-security"]
```

How can I authenticate when querying druid?

Should I add a username and password to the HTTP header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use basic authentication. You should just be able to send your query to druid with an URL like this:

```
https://username:password@your-druid.com/druid/v2/sql
```

Comment: Thanks. How you get that information? from druid docs? I can't find above information in https://druid.apache.org/docs/0.16.1-incubating/design/index.html

Comment: I see in the common.runtime.properties file which you have posted above several credential settings. By default you should be able to login with "admin" and then the password which is specified in `druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicAuthenticator.initialAdminPassword`. See also this page for more information about security and druid: https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/druid-basic-security.html